# Understanding multiple parameter types in Scala Type Parameterization

Tags: scala

I understand the following is an example of upper bound type parameterization in scala, where T must be a subtype of Command.

```
def getSomeValue[T <: Command] = ...
```

However, Today I found the following implementation of type parameterization with multiple parameter types and as I'm a beginner in scala, I'm quite unable to understand what actually it does. Is this means T must be subtype of either Command, Foo or Bar?

```
def getSomeValue[T <: Command : Foo : Bar] = ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stand-alone colon, in a type parameter specification, is actually shorthand (syntactic sugar) for a longer, and rather complicated, parameter invocation.

Example: `def f[N: Numeric](n: N) = ...`

is really: `def f[N](n: N)(implicit ev: Numeric[N]) = ...`

Meaning that when `f(x)` is invoked there has to be an implicit in scope that matches `Numeric[x.type]`.

So, in your example code fragment: `def getSomeValue[T <: Command : Foo : Bar] = ...`

The compiler turns that into, roughly, the following:

```
def getSomeValue[T <: Command](implicit ev1: Foo[T], ev2: Bar[T]) = ...
```

We can demonstrate this by providing just enough skeletal code to actually make it compilable.

```
class Command {}
class Foo[F] {}
class Bar[B] {}
class Cmd extends Command

def getSomeValue[T <: Command : Foo : Bar](t: T) = t

getSomeValue(new Cmd)(new Foo[Cmd], new Bar[Cmd])
                  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  // implicit parameters supplied explicitly
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation with example.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this means T must be subtype of either Command, Foo or Bar?

No, the upper bound is still required for `T`. You now must also have an *implicit* instance of `Foo[T]` and `Bar[T]` in scope when this method is called. This is called [Context Bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds), and it syntax sugar for:

```
def getSomeValue[T <: Command](implicit f: Foo[T], b: Bar[T])
```

If you're unaware of what implicit means, [refer to the documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html) for more.

Comment: I never knew about the Context Bounds. Thank you for pointing that out. :)